# What's the difference between drive upgrades?

Tags: vehicles, stars-without-number

I'm making a starship in Stars without Number. Specifically, I'm trying to decide what drive to put on it. However, I can't find anything on specifically how having a better drive affects me – there's a couple of generic descriptions that say that it "moves faster" but nothing (at least that I can see) that says, for example, that the time in days of an interstellar journey is 10 less the level of the drive.

What effect do spike drive upgrades have? Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find more info in the section *Starship Travel* in chapter 4 *Systems*:

> All transit time is divided by the rating of the ship's spike drive. A drive-1 rated ship would make the course in the base time, while a drive-2 rated ship would require half the time [...]

and

> A drive cannot drill more hexes in a single jump than the rating of the drive.

And it also plays a role in combat (section *Starship Combat*):

> Each ships captain writes down what metadimensional phase his ship will occupy and what phase his guns will target. All ships can fly and shoot into 'real space', phase 0. The maximum phase into which they can fly or shoot is equal to their spike drive rating.

So, a ship with a higher drive rating than the opponent can avoid most damage in combat.

Comment: I knew I'd missed something! Many thanks, especially for the location. I'll be sure to check it next time.